# How can I speed up the iOS speech

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, instapaper

Ever since I update to iOS 9.3, text to speech has been super-slow in Instapaper and Pocket.

I tried going to **settings -> general -> accessibility -> speech** and changing the speed, but it's not helping.

Got any advice for how to fix this? (Or is this a bug in this version of iOS?)

Comment: What model of iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch do you have?

Comment: I have an iPhone 6S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got an email from Instapaper about this:

"Our apologies about that, it's an issue with how we access iOS's voice protocols that came up with the 9.3 update. We've already fixed it, confirmed the fix in beta, and the 7.1.2 release with those fixes is currently awaiting approval for release from Apple."

**update**: on April 11, 2016 the update hit the App Store and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 9.3, iPhone 6s and 6s Plus can utilize Offline Dictation. Check Settings > General > Keyboard and try toggling "Enable Dictation" off then back on.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. In case my question wasn't written clearly, I'm trying to fix speech, not dictation. Are dictation and speech related in iOS?

Comment: @AndrewWarner Oh, I just misread it as speech-to-text. I got it backwards.

Comment: Ah. No prob. I really miss hearing hearing my articles read to me in double time.

Comment: @AndrewWarner Did you try restarting it?

Comment: Restarting the phone? Yes. Restarting speech? Not sure how to do that. Do you know?

Comment: @AndrewWarner No, I just meant restarting the iPhone. Did you try backing your iPhone up to iTunes and then restoring the backup?

Comment: That's pretty drastic because it takes so long to get things back to the way they were. I'd like to try other options first.

Comment: @AndrewWarner The backup and restore takes awhile (maybe an hour or two), but once restored the iPhone is just like it was. But, maybe someone else can think of something. If backing up and restoring the backup doesn't work, it's likely an iOS bug.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think a restore will solve it. According to this article the Alex voice was slowed. I just need to find a way to speed it again http://www.applevis.com/blog/apple-ios-news/apple-releases-ios-93-number-new-features-and-improvements